Matching Unknown Chainsaw Sounds to Known Models Using Signal Processing
I am working on a signal processing task involving sound recordings of chainsaws. I have several recordings from known chainsaws and several recordings from unknown chainsaws.
The goal is to match each unknown chainsaw recording to the correct known chainsaw, if possible.
My Current Approach:

Perform a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) on each signal to extract the spectral components (harmonics).
Compute the Euclidean distance between the spectra of the known and unknown signals as a similarity metric.

My Questions:

Could this approach work for this type of problem?
How could I determine a suitable threshold to decide whether two signals belong to the same chainsaw?
Should I somehow use power spectral density?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I don't think this question can be answered without a whole lot of chainsaw acoustics expertise.  Without being one, the answer to all three of your questions is "maybe", or perhaps "maybe, if you start with hundreds of different chainsaws".  Except for the third one -- yes, you should probably use power spectral density somehow, because that's what's going to be best preserved in uncontrolled recordings.  Don't depend on absolute frequency, though, because the saw speeds will change as they're loaded down.
